# Separate configuration file for two openshift git remotes (testing/production)

Tags: django, git, openshift

I haven't been able to figure out something that may be simple/easy.  I have a git repository of a django web app, and I've been pushing it to Openshift for testing.  The act of pushing causes the code to deploy and run on Openshift. Now, I've created another copy of my app on Openshift for production use, and some of the setup files (notably in the django configuration file settings.py) are very slightly different.  I think I need to have two versions of some files, one for each different remote, so I can push to one Openshift remote for testing, and then push to the other Openshift remote for deployment.  Only a few files will be different between the two, most will be identical.  For most files, it's just the frequency of the pushes that will be different (stamp out the bugs in development before deploying to production.)

I'm starting to get the hang of git, but my mind is still wrapped around subversion, so maybe there's something simple I'm missing.  Am I supposed to create a separate branch in the repository for production, and then "push" from development to production when bugs are ironed out, and then have the production remote on openshift only attached to that branch?

Is this an Openshift specific issue?  Or is it something so simple and basic with git that I don't even know how to google it correctly?

(In Subversion, FWIW, I'd have a separate branch for production, and I'd "merge/reintegrate" development code into the production branch, and then commit it to the repository.  The pulling of the production code from the subversion server to the running production machine would be a separate step.)

Comment: "I'd have a separate branch for production, and I'd "merge/reintegrate" development code into the production branch" - you can do the same thing in git. You could easily have two separate branches like you said: just merge a dev branch into master (or whatever) once your bugs are fixed. I don't think this is a an OS specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just detecting if you are on an Openshift server and execute your desired setup code base on that?

```
Import os

if 'OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME' in os.environ:
  # do production setup stuff here 
else: 
  # do development setup stuff here
```

Comment: I like this answer the best so far.  Thanks!  However, both dev and production are on open shift, so I would have to use `if os.environ('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME') == 'ProductionAppName' `

Answer (score 1):

In order to have separate settings for dev and pro, you can do the following:

1. Create a settings folder near your current `settings.py` file.
2. Create `__init__.py` file (see content below) in new settings folder to register it as a python module.

**__init__.py**

```
from .base import *

try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass

try:
    from .production import *
except:
    pass
```

3. Create `base.py`, `local.py`, and `production.py` in new settings folder. `base.py` is most likely should contain the same code as your old `settings.py` had, with only one difference - the `DEBUG` setting should be set to `False`. Write the necessary code for your dev in `local.py` and set `DEBUG=True` in it. In `production.py` specify all settings for pro with `DEBUG = False` and the next condition at the very beginning of the file:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings

   if not settings.DEBUG:
       #write all your settings in that block
   ```
4. Now you can add `local.py` to .gitignore, to push only `production.py` settings file to server. So, you'll have different settings in dev and pro.
5. Rename old `setting.py` file to `old_settings.py` or whatever.

I think the similar way can be used to specify other separate files for dev and pro, however, i have not check this.

Comment: Really great suggestion and a general overview of how to do things like this.  Thanks.